# Android system not using the configured DNS server

Tags: wi-fi, networking, dns

Running android 10.

[Network app](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/com.github.axet.pingutils) shows correct the 2 DNS servers that i configured for my wifi, in ipv4, as well as 2 mobile data DNSes in ipv6.

But regardless of my configured servers, it never passes through them. Using a [DNS query tester](https://f-droid.org/packages/androdns.android.leetdreams.ch.androdns), it looks like it defaults to the first mobile data DNS, despite data being turned off. The request fails, probably since my router doesn't support ipv6. It can query my local DNS just fine when explicitly used.

The only requests ever logged by my local DNS server are from google.com, connectivitycheck.gstatic.com, dns.quad9.net for some reason, and ONE app that follows policy (an XMPP client).

Using a [packet sniffer](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/com.summer.netcloud), it looked like everything was going through 8.8.8.8, though i'm not sure exactly how the app works.

I also tried forcing the DNS under a local VPN with [this app](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.itxtech.daedalus), which definitely blocked all calls to 8.8.8.8 because then no domain names could be resolved, effectively blocking internet. Explicit calls to my DNS server still work.

There's a lot of weird android behavior, but this just seems like a bug.

Comment: Check network settings if privacy DNS is enabled. If it is enabled all DNS server configuration received via DHCP are ignored and instead one of the large DNS servers like 8.8.8.8 that supports DNS over HTTPS/TLS are used.

Comment: Thanks Robert, it was private DNS. I assumed my phone didn't even have it after snooping around wifi settings so much, but there it is, and i had even configured it in the past to use quad9, which explains the bootstrapping queries.